# Setting the default value in the drop down list in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the default value in the drop down list of angular JS. Below is my code:

```
<div class="dropdownIcon">
    <select name="actions" id="actions"
        ng-options="option.Value for option in Data.Actions"
        ng-focus="ActionsLabel = true" ng-blur="ActionsLabel = false;"
        ng-model="Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput.Action"/>
        <label for="actions" class="labelColor"
            ng-class="{'dropdownLabelFloat' : (ActionsLabel || Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput.Action != null), 'dropdownLabel' : !ActionsLabel && !Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput.Action  }">
            Action
        </label>
</div>
```

I want to set the default value to '---' and Id=0. In my controller, I have the following code:

```
var inputValues = angular.copy($scope.Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput);
             
$scope.Data.EmployeeStatusChangeSaveInSession = {
     EffectiveDateString: inputValues.EffectiveDate.toString(),
     Action: inputValues.Action.Value,
};
```

I tried to put this code in my controller in order to make the default value to 0:

```
$scope.Data.Action = 0;
```

I wrote the above line right after this line in my controller:

```
var inputValues = angular.copy($scope.Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput);
```

By putting this line, the selected value of the drop-down list did not change to '---'.

If user does not select any value in the drop down then '---' should be preselected. If user does select some value then that values should pass to the controller.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pre-set the value, you have to give the `ng-model` an actual value. Here I added

```
EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput: {
    Action: 'value3'
}
```

However, you also need to form your `ng-options` so it has name/value pairs, using this syntax:

```
ng-options="option.Name as option.Value for option in Data.Actions"
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.Data = {
      Actions: [{
        Value: 'test1',
        Name: 'value1'
      }, {
        Value: 'test2',
        Name: 'value2'
      }, {
        Value: 'test3',
        Name: 'value3'
      }],
      EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput: {
        Action: 'value3'
      }
    }

  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="dropdownIcon">
    <select name="actions" id="actions" ng-options="option.Name as option.Value for option in Data.Actions" ng-focus="ActionsLabel = true" ng-blur="ActionsLabel = false;" ng-model="Data.EmployeeStatusChangeRoutingInput.Action"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```